# Car and Cdr in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

So I've been learn Scheme for school, and have run into a situation using `car` and `cdr` series that doesn't quite make sense to me.

So given a list: `(define x '(1 2 3 4 5))`

How come `(caddddr x)` spits an error at me, while `(cddddr x)` returns `(5)` and `(car (cddddr x))` returns `5`.

Isn't `(caddddr x)` the same as `(car (cddddr x))`?

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: @chepner `Reference to undefined identifier: caddddr`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only put a few `a`'s and`d`'s in there :-) check the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28part._.Pair_.Accessor_.Shorthands%29), between the initial `c` and the final `r` there can be between 1 and 4 characters in any combination of `a`'s and `d`'s. If you need to access a specific element beyond that, consider using [`list-ref`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list-ref%29%29), which returns an element given its zero-based index on the list, for example:

```
(define x '(1 2 3 4 5))
(list-ref x 4)
=> 5
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know there was a limit!

Answer (score 4):

Because the scheme definition goes up to `(cddddr pair)‌‌` but not beyond.  In the words of the specification for `car` and `cdr` and friends: "Arbitrary compositions, up to four deep, are provided."  See (for example):

```
http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_620
```

And as has been noted elsewhere, [list-ref](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-2.html#node_toc_node_sec_11.9) is probably what you want in this case.